# Texmaker (WinXP) : How to open documents in separate windows?

Tags: windows, texmaker

Is it me or is it actually not possible to open Latex files in separate Windows with Texmaker? Does anyone know of a way?

Answer (score 5):

TeXmaker doesn't seem to allow multiple instances, but [TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) (a fork of TeXmaker) can be started multiple times using [--start-always](http://texstudio.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/texstudio/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#SECTION38) option.

Comment: I think I might just try that. The thing about TeXmaker is that there are some very good things about it, but there are other things that are extremely irritating. A better TeXmaker cannot be a bad thing. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I created the following batch script to be able to run multiple instances of Texmaker. Once you opened a window, run this script and you will be able to open another instance. For this script you need the [Sysinternals Handle utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) to be in some folder of your `%path%` variable or in the same directory as the script.

```
@echo off
rem Determine Process ID
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%x in ('tasklist /FI "imagename EQ texmaker.exe" ^| find "texmaker.exe"') do (
    rem Find Lock handle and kill it. Then delete the lockfile
    for /F "delims=: tokens=1,2,3*" %%i in ('handle -a -p texmaker.exe ^| find "lockfile"') do (
        echo Killing handle %%i of processid %%y
        echo y | handle -c %%i -p %%y>nul
        del "%%k">nul 2>&1
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)