# Latex editor for Linux that allows multiple instances

Tags: editors, linux

I have always used Texmaker, but I'm at the point now where I am writing multiple documents at the same time (e.g., thesis and paper). Additionally, I like to have my work organized into different workspaces.

This is where Texmaker fails me. It only allows a single instance of the application at a time. As far as I can tell, there is no way to have two instances of Texmaker open at the same time. I have tried Kile, and it is the same thing.

I was just wondering if anyone has experience with other latex editors that support multiple instances? I know of TexMakerX, but the installation isn't clean, and I forget the steps I had to take to make it work once (I also remember being underwhelmed once I installed it...). I'm also familiar with emacs+auctex, but at the end of the day, I would much rather use an IDE like editor.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides should answer this question.

Comment: What do you need that emacs and AucTeX does not provide?
The only real downside with those is to learn how to use them but if you are familiar with them I do not see any reason no to use them.

Comment: You can try with SublimeText (http://www.sublimetext.com)

Comment: There are prebuilt packages (e.g. .deb, .rpm) available for TeXstudio (formerly TeXmakerX), so the installation is straightforward.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35351

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/) can be called with the `--new` argument, launching a new instance.

```
kile --new
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I just ended up using one of the texstudio pre-built packages (I was always compiling from sources before... d'oh).